# How to use a class constant into a class attribute in PHP?

Tags: php, oop, class, properties, constants

Here's the code that won't work :

```
class MyClass
{
    const myconst = 'somevalue';

    private $myvar = array( 0 => 'do something with '.self::myconst );
}
```

Seems that class constants are not available at "compile time", but only at runtime.
Does anyone know any workaround ? (define won't work)

Thanks

Comment: if you're looking for something like a C macro, PHP doesn't work that way. besides, there's no "compile time". PHP is an interpreter.

Comment: The people who wrote the manual seem to be under the impression that there is a "compile time". http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

Comment: There is a "compile time" (sort of), since PHP internals convert text code to bytecode. See http://sebastian-bergmann.de/archives/868-PHP-Compiler-Internals.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem in your class declaration is not that you are using a constant, but that you are using an expression.

> Class member variables are called "properties". (...) They are defined by using one of the keywords public, protected, or private, followed by a normal variable declaration. This declaration may include an initialization, **but this initialization must be a constant value**--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.

This simple declaration, for example, will not compile (parse error):

```
class MyClass{
    private $myvar = 3+2;
}
```

But if we alter your class declaration to use the simple constant, rather than a string concatenated with that constant it will work as expected.

```
class MyClass{
    const myconst = 'somevalue';
    public $myvar = array( 0 => self::myconst );
}

$obj = new MyClass();
echo $obj->myvar[0];
```

As a work-around you could initialize your properties in the constructor:

```
class MyClass{
    const myconst = 'somevalue';
    public $myvar;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->myvar = array( 0 => 'do something with '.self::myconst );
    }
}
$obj = new MyClass();
echo $obj->myvar[0];
```

I hope this helps you,
Alin

Comment: Yes I knew that... I first tried to "const" my array, but PHP does not allow it. And it seems that the basic "define" (the real one, the #define from C/C++) does not exists in PHP. So, anyone has a workaround ?

Comment: @Antoine See the latest edit. This is all I could think of and I would say that it's an acceptable method to initialize in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Note that for **PHP 5.6 and above**, it's possible to do so.

See https://secure.php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php:

> It is now possible to provide a scalar expression involving numeric and string literals and/or constants in contexts where PHP previously expected a static value, such as constant and property declarations and default function arguments.